# Serving http over my laptop public ip address - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache, http

I'm testing a feature locally, and instead of using an EC2 instance, I want to use my own laptop:

```
python3 -m http.server
Serving HTTP on :: port 8000 (http://[::]:8000/) ...
```

if I do `curl http://localhost:8000` it will work and the webpage is fetched. However if I do `curl http://<my-ip-address>:8000` I'm getting:

```
<html><head><title>504 Gateway Timeout</title></head>
<body><h1>Gateway Timeout</h1>
<p>Server error - server <my-ip-address> is unreachable at this moment.<br><br>Please retry the request or contact your administrator.<br></p>
</body></html>
```

how can I enable my IP address to serve in the browser through the public ip address assigned to the laptop?

Comment: Is your laptop directly connected to the public Internet, i.e. you don't have a private network (like 192.168.x.x) and a NAT router?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the module `http.server` with the bind address (0.0.0.0 or your local address)  as follows:

```
python3 -m http.server --bind 0.0.0.0
```

In your case, it seems that something is already listening on the address :8080 because 504 is an HTTP status,
you can try to run it on another port, make sure it is available (netstat -an).

```
python3 -m http.server --bind 0.0.0.0 8888
```